# How to get a reference of a view to a fragment if the fragment is inflated inside another layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a parent layout that is used to inflate various fragments. On one such fragment layout I need to access the view elements inside the fragment class. 
I'm using below code to get a reference for a text view inside the fragments layout.

***CreateTaskFragment.java***

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        View view = getView();
        endDateView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.estimated_end_input);
        endDateView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Date","I'm clicked");
            }
        });
    }
```

The **endDateView** is returning **null**.

**fragment_create_task.xml**

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.tetrissoft.dailyplanner.CreateTaskFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/estimated_end_date"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/estimated_end_label"/>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/task_end_date_input"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/estimated_end_input"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <!-- The Main Content Layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/fab_button"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!--  The Navigation Drawer-->
    <ListView
       ...
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**How can I get the reference to the view elements of  CreateTaskFragment?**

Comment: Copy below method in your fragment and remove your onActivityCreated method from fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy below method in your fragment and remove your onActivityCreated method from fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_task, container, false);

    TextView endDateView = (TextView)rootView .findViewById(R.id.estimated_end_input);
    endDateView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Date","I'm clicked");
        }
    });

 return rootView;

 }
```

Comment: It worked actually I didn't defined the id in layout which I was passing to findViewById() method.